# Image Thresholding with Distance measure

Tags: python, opencv

I'm new to OpenCV, and I'm currently wondering if there's a way of image thresholding or clustering to be applied to pixel distance (euclidean distance) to figure out if an object exists in an image.

Say, I have 3 images, one with the main object, the other one with a arbitrary background with the main object, and finally one with the arbitrary background without the object.

I managed to calculate the distance between corner points using `cv2.goodFeaturesToTrack()`

But is there an image thresholding method that I can use for distance?

I have read many thresholding methods on the net, but they seem to apply to only grayscale images. The ones like `cv2.threshold` and `cv2.adaptiveThreshold`

What other image thresholding methods can I use for distance?

---

**EDIT**

The below are three images:

[image][image][image]

As you can see, the Rubik's Cube is the main object benchmark. I managed to get the corners as well as measure the distance between corners using Euclidean's Distance formula.

What thresholding/clustering technique can I consider to apply to the distance value to determine if the object exists in the images?

Comment: You can threshold color images using [inrange](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4.5/d2/de8/group__core__array.html#ga48af0ab51e36436c5d04340e036ce981). The HSV colorspace works better the RGB  ([example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54726481/10699171)). If you can separate out the object, you could use the mask or masked image to do pixel calculations. But it depends a lot on your specific case. If you can upload the images you describe we can help you better.

Comment: I have added the images and some additional explanations