# Comparing and plotting regions of the same color over a dataset of a few hundred images

Tags: python, matlab, opencv, image-processing, image-segmentation

A chem student asked me for help with plotting image segmenetation: 
A stationary camera takes a picture of the experimental setup every second over a period of a few minutes, so like 300 images yield.

The relevant parts in the setup are two adjacent layers of differently-colored foams observed from the side, a 2-color sandwich shrinking from both sides, basically, except one of the foams evaporates a bit faster.

---

*I'd like to segment each of the images in the way that would let me plot both foam regions' "width" against time.*

Here is a "diagram" :)
[I want to go from here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o3M8p.jpg) --> [To here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hqH0z.jpg)

Ideally, given a few hundred of such shots, in which only the widths change, I get an array of scalars back that I can plot. (Going to look like a harmonic series on either side of the x-axis)

---

I have a bit of python and matlab experience, but have never used OpenCV or Image Processing toolbox in matlab, or actually never dealt with any computer vision in general. Could you guys throw like a roadmap of what packages/functions to use or steps one should take and i'll take it from there?

I'm not sure how to address these things:

-selecting at which slice along the length of the slice the algorithm measures the width(i.e. if the foams are a bit uneven), although this can be ignored.

-which library to use to segment regions of the image based on their color, (some k-means shenanigans probably), and selectively store the spatial parameters of the resulting segments?

-how to iterate that above over a number of files.

Thank you kindly in advance!

Comment: Its a bit difficult to understand what you want.  Maybe draw a sample of what you want in terms of block diagram or flowchar. E.g for a given  input set, whats desired output. Also it is Sunday night, guess Chem PHD are more stressful  than CS.  I can help you write the code. but need better description.

Comment: @DrYuanShenghai hey, doc, updated the question. Thanks a bunch, i just need a few pointers i think, and would like to figure out the code myself!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assume your Intensity will be different after converting into gray scale ( if not, just convert to other color space like HSV or LAB, then just use one of the components)

```
img = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
```

**First**, Threshold your grayscaled input into a few bands

```
ret,thresh1 = cv.threshold(img,128,255,cv.THRESH_BINARY)
ret,thresh2 = cv.threshold(img,27,255,cv.THRESH_BINARY_INV)
ret,thresh3 = cv.threshold(img,77,255,cv.THRESH_TRUNC)
ret,thresh4 = cv.threshold(img,97,255,cv.THRESH_TOZERO)
ret,thresh5 = cv.threshold(img,227,255,cv.THRESH_TOZERO_INV)
```

The value should be tested out by your actual data. Here Im just give a example

Clean up the segmented image using median filter with a radius larger than 9. I do expect some noise. You can also use ROI here to help remove part of noise. But personally I`m lazy, I just wrote program to handle all cases and angle

```
threshholed_images_aftersmoothing = cv2.medianBlur(threshholed_images,9)
```

Each band will be corresponding to one color (layer). Now you should have N segmented image from one source. where N is the number of layers you wish to track

**Second** use opencv function bounding rect to find location and width/height of each Layer AKA each **threshholed_images_aftersmoothing**. Eg. boundingrect on each sub-segmented images.

```
C++: Rect boundingRect(InputArray points)
Python: cv2.boundingRect(points) → retval¶
```

**Last**, the rect have x,y, height and width property. You can use a simple sorting order to sort from top to bottom layer based on rect attribute x.  Run though all vieo to obtain the x(layer id) , height vs time graph.

```
Rect API

Public Attributes
_Tp     **height**   // this is what you are looking for

_Tp     width  

_Tp     **x**   // this tells you the position of the band

_Tp     y
```

By plot the corresponding heights (|AB| or |CD|) over time, you can obtain the graph you needed.

The more correct way is to use Kalman filter to track the position and height  graph as I would expect some sort of bubble will occur and will interfere with the height of the layers.

To be honest, i didnt expect a chem student to be good at this. Haha good luck

Anything wrong you can find me here or Email me if i`m not watching stackoverflow

Comment: this is incredibly prompt and very helpful. tyvm, sir

Answer (score 0):

You can select a region of interest straight down the middle of the foams, a few pixels wide. If you stack these regions for each image it will show the shrink over time.

If for example you use 3 pixel width for the roi, the result of 300 images will be a 900 pixel wide image, where the left is the start of the experiment and the right is the end. The following image can help you understand:

[image]

Though I have not fully tested it, this code should work. Note that there must only be images in the folder you reference.

```
import cv2
import numpy as np 
import os

# path to folder that holds the images
path = '.'
# dimensions of roi
x = 0
y = 0
w = 3
h = 100

# store references to all images
all_images = os.listdir(path)
# sort images
all_images.sort()
# create empty result array
result = np.empty([h,0,3],dtype=np.uint8)

for image in all_images:
        # load image
        img = cv2.imread(path+'/'+image)
        # get the region of interest
        roi = img[y:y+h,x:x+w]
        # add the roi to previous results 
        result = np.hstack((result,roi))

# optinal: save result as image
# cv2.imwrite('result.png',result)
# display result - can also plot with matplotlib
cv2.imshow('Result', result)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Update after question edit:
If the foams have different colors, your can use easily separate them by color by converting the image you hsv and using `inrange` [(example)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54726481/10699171). This creates a mask (=2D array with values from 0-255, one for each pixel) that you can use to calculate average height and extract the parameters and area of the image.

You can find a script to help you find the HSV colors for separation on this [GitHub](https://github.com/twenty-twenty/opencv_basic_color_separator)